# Calculating Categorical Quotients

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to practice calculating categorical quotients and I ran into this example. I am unable to get the answer and was wondering if someone can help?

Let $G = Z/3Z =$ $\{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$, where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity. Let $G$
act on $^{2}$ via $\omega(x, y) = (\omega x, \omega y)$. Find the categorical quotient of $^{2}$
by G.

Comment: What is $A$ in the question?

Comment: Considering the coordinates in the action, I suspect $A^2$ is $\mathbb{A}^2$.