# Categorical Quotient and group actions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions

I am trying to practice calculating categorical quotients and I ran into this example. I am unable to get the answer and was wondering if someone can help?

Let $G = Z/3Z =$ $\{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$, where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity. Let $G$
act on $^{2}$ via $\omega(x, y) = (\omega x, \omega y)$. Find the categorical quotient of $^{2}$
by G.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Categorical Quotients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837226/calculating-categorical-quotients)

Comment: When speaking about a categorical quotient, you have to specify which category you are working in. Which is it? The category of (affine) schemes?

Comment: Yes, it is the category of affine schemes

Comment: the quotient categorie of the product categorie  $A^2$  by the
action of $G$ have as objet the classes of objet of the categorie
product $A^2$, that is the orbit of an objet in $A^2$ under the
action of $G$, then the morphisms are class morphisms of $(f,g) $
witch respect the orbits (compatibility of $(f,g)$ with the $G$
action),

Comment: @m.idaya: this is irrelevant. $\mathbb{A}^2$ here describes an affine scheme, not a category.

Answer (score 1):

The category of affine schemes is the opposite of the category of commutative rings, and taking opposites switches limits and colimits, so in general the categorical quotient $\left( \text{Spec } R \right) / G$ is the spectrum $\text{Spec } R^G$ of the fixed point subring. Hence you want to compute the subring of $R = k[x, y]$ ($k$ a field containing $\omega$, and in particular not of characteristic $3$) fixed under the action of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ generated by

$$x \mapsto \omega x, y \mapsto \omega y.$$

It shouldn't be hard to convince yourself that this subring is $k[x^3, x^2 y, x y^2, y^3]$; equivalently, it's the subalgebra of $k[x, y]$ of polynomials with total degree $3$.

If you want to write $\text{Spec } k[x^3, x^2 y, xy^2, y^3]$ as a closed subscheme of affine space then you need a presentation. You can take the generators to be $a = x^3, b = x^2 y, c = x y^2, d = y^3$ (exercise: you need at least this many generators), and the relations they satisfy are (I think) generated by

$$ac = b^2, bd = c^2, ad = bc.$$

Comment: In the definition of the categorical quotient we have an affine variety and a morphism. What would the morphism be in this case?

Comment: @French_Warrior: on the ring side it's the inclusion of $k[x^3, x^2 y, xy^2, y^3]$ into $k[x, y]$.

Comment: *polynomials with monomials of total degree divisible by $3$, excuse me